# Monte Carlo simulation to predict presidential election

Tags: java

I had an algorithms and data structures lab today, the lab was to use a monte carlo simulation to figure the odds of 3 specific candidates coming in the bottom 3(in any order, there are 6 candidates in total).

I feel like my algorithm should work, although its just not finding any scenarios where they are all in the bottom three, even when I run the simulation thousands of times.

The candidates that I need to check if they are in the bottom 3 are `pc`,`gd`,`sg`.

Here is my code..

```
import java.util.*;

public class Lab4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rd = new Random();

        double mh = (double)25/26;
        //System.out.println(mh);

        double pc = (double)1/10;
        //System.out.println(pc);

        double sg = (double)1/66;
        //System.out.println(sg);

        double lnr = (double)1/80;
        //System.out.println(lnr);

        double jf = (double)1/250;
        //System.out.println(jf);

        double gd = (double)1/500;
        //System.out.println(gd);


        int count = 0;
        int votes = 200000;
        int numSimulations = 5000;

        int[] ar1 = new int[6];

        for(int i = 1; i <= numSimulations; i++)
        {           
            int mhCount = 0;
            int pcCount = 0;
            int sgCount = 0;
            int lnrCount = 0;
            int jfCount = 0;
            int gdCount = 0;

            for(int j = 1; j <= votes; j++)
            {
                double randomValue = rd.nextDouble()* 1.0951899766899766;

                if(randomValue <= mh)
                {
                    mhCount++;
                }
                else if(randomValue <= mh + pc)
                {
                    pcCount++;
                }
                else if(randomValue <= mh + pc + sg)
                {
                    sgCount++;
                }
                else if(randomValue <= mh + pc + sg + lnr)
                {
                    lnrCount++;
                }
                else if(randomValue <= mh + pc + sg + lnr + jf)
                {
                    jfCount++;
                }
                else if(randomValue <= mh + pc + sg + lnr + jf + gd)
                {
                    gdCount++;
                }
            }

            ar1[0] = mhCount;
            ar1[1] = pcCount;
            ar1[2] = sgCount;
            ar1[3] = lnrCount;
            ar1[4] = jfCount;
            ar1[5] = gdCount;

            Arrays.sort(ar1);

            if(ar1[0] == pcCount || ar1[1] == pcCount || ar1[2] == pcCount)
            {

                if(ar1[0] == gdCount || ar1[1] == gdCount || ar1[2] == gdCount)
                {

                    if(ar1[0] == sgCount || ar1[1] == sgCount || ar1[2] == sgCount)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }


        }

        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.println((double)count/(double)numSimulations);
    }   
}
```

Has anyone got any ideas as to how I can make this algorithm better? specifically the if,else ifs where I am distributing the votes... 
Is there a better way to do this? because the odds of them coming in the bottom three *have* to be greater than 0, even its its 0.0007.. and my algorithm is just not picking them up as ever being there.. many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the individual chances of winning (25/26 + 1/10 + ...) is ~1.09519, but you're only selecting random numbers between 0 and 1.0705632798573974. Change that multiplier and run more than a thousand cases and you should see the results you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I had just recently changed the odds as they have changed and forgot to change this also, still after running it with this over 5000 times, still getting 0 counts of them candidates in the bottom 3..

Comment: With your vote count so high (200000) the top candidates will almost always come out on top. There are so many votes being cast -- and the top candidates are so much stronger than the bottom ones -- that it's hard for a lower candidate to "get lucky" and move to the top.

Comment: Also, if you want to see if pc, gd, and sg are the bottom three candidates, you could do this:

    if (Math.min(pc, Math.min(gd, sg)) > Math.max(mh, Math.max(lnr, jf)) 
        count++;

Comment: Sorry -- typo above.  Meant to say this:

Also, if you want to see if pc, gd, and sg are the bottom three candidates, you could do this:

    if (Math.max(pc, Math.max(gd, sg)) < Math.min(mh, Math.min(lnr, jf)) count++;

That is, if the largest of pc/gd/sg is still smaller than the smallest of mh/lnr/jf, then pc/gd/sg must be the lowest three candidates.

Comment: Yes that is a good point, more efficient, I will implement this.. thanks!

Comment: Yes your answer was 100% right, thank you for your input!